# Does the following banner mandate wearing a hijab in an Egyptian school?

Tags: islam, egypt

[This article](https://www.worldwatchmonitor.org/2016/11/4703212/) claims the following banner mandates the hijab (an Islamic head-cover) and it was posted outside Egyptian schools.

> [image]
>
> > **A banner mandating the ‘hijab’** has been posted outside schools.

The same article is posted in [this](https://voiceofthepersecuted.wordpress.com/) and [this](https://pray.interserve.org/christians-children-bullied-at-schools-in-egypt/) site.

Is it true?

Comment: -Can you provide a reasonable explanation of what your question is and if required add as much details as you can since the current details only mention the article link and not the country where this mandate is applicable?

Comment: @pericles316 Updated.

Comment: I haven't downvoted the question, but unless the Arabic in the photo has some unusual content, the claim doesn't seem very outlandish.

Comment: If this were true, what would be surprising about it? Plenty of schools in the West have mandatory dress codes.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The claim is about Egypt. The ruler Sisi is a secularist dictator who killed thousands of people to stay in power. His administration is trying to [ban the veil](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/africa/egypt-drafts-bill-to-ban-niqab-veil-in-public-places-a6920701.html) not mandate it.

Comment: @DJClayworth "If this were true, what would be surprising about it? Plenty of schools in the West have mandatory dress codes." That's a good point but the current ruler of Egypt is a secular authoritarian dictator. He cracks down on religious activities that may threaten his rule.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin So when it's done in Western countries that's OK, but when it's done in Egypt by a dictator that's somehow wrong.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Nobody is talking about it being "right" or "wrong", except you.  But the claim would seem to suggest that the government is doing something inconsistent with its stated policies, so that in itself would be notable.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin The sign doesn't correspond to any national policy, it's just a sign at a particular school.  The national policy is that head covering is permitted but not required.  But some schools weren't following the national policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This photo was taken by [Lamya Lotfey](https://web.facebook.com/lamya.lotfey), a Egyptian Coptic Christian. She posted this photo in her Facebook public profile on **Sunday, October 16, 2016 at 5:01 pm** (according to GMT +6, timezone of where I live).

[image: no description]

According to my native Arabic speaker friend, the photo is "instructions how the dress of school must be." The photo was then published by [AL Ahram newspaper](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/64/246582/Egypt/Politics-/Campaign-calls-for-end-to-forcing-girls-to-wear-he.aspx) (credit to DavePhD) with the following caption.

> A sign stipulating Islamic veil as a mandatory part of girls' dress
>   code at a school in Egypt's Sharqiya governorate.

[Archive.org link](http://web.archive.org/save/_embed/https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10153941204516179&set=a.63667276178.85302.546946178&type=3&permPage=1) to original photo.

Answer (score 1):

The image is that of "A sign stipulating Islamic veil as a mandatory part of girls' dress code at a school in Egypt's Sharqiya governorate".

A higher resolution version and further explanation is available at [Campaign calls for end to forcing girls to wear headscarves in some schools in Egypt](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/64/246582/Egypt/Politics-/Campaign-calls-for-end-to-forcing-girls-to-wear-he.aspx)

Comment: +1 I assume it's correct. Just an FYI, Al Ahram is Sisi's propaganda machine.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin you could try asking Lamya Lotfey on facebook if you want a first-hand account.  It's her daughter that was physically abused and I think it is her photograph of the sign.

Comment: Dave, I did hunt down the original source. Ha ha.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin Nice work!